# PHP set words to a value

Tags: php, words

How can I set words to a value?

For example:

```
[JUMP]Take a new card[JUMP]
```

Now I want to pick the words/text between the `[JUMP]` and set it now to a value, for example: `$word`

How can I do this with PHP? Is there a possibility with `str_replace` ?

Comment: I think [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is the way to go! Maybe you can even solve this by yourself :D (If you get stuck just make an edit and write: "I found preg_match_all(), but don't know where to start" or "I tried this with preg_match_all", but it doesn't do what I want)

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can try,

```
$string = "[JUMP]Take a new card[JUMP]";
if( preg_match('/\[JUMP\](.*)\[JUMP\]/', $string, $matches) ) {

    echo $matches[1];
    // output: Take a new card
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally I don't suggest libraries but you might find the [PECL BBCode library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) of use here.

The best place to start would be with [bbcode_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php). You can then define what codes you want to parse and what you want to replace them with. Avoids any messes with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done with `str_replace`. Try this:

```
echo str_replace("[JUMP]","","[JUMP]Take a new card[JUMP]");
```

It replaces the characters "[JUMP]" in the string "[JUMP]Take a new card[JUMP]" with empty string.
If you want to get results with variables:

```
<?php
  $word = "[JUMP]Take a new card[JUMP]";
  $delete = "[JUMP]";
  $value = str_replace($delete,"",$word);
  echo $value;
?>
```

Comment: And what if there is more text around those jumps? This will fail then

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Just answered to " Is there a possibility with str_replace ?" question.